# using "query user /server:XXX" command in c++ windows form application

Tags: c++-cli

I'm developing a small app to find out the users logged into the server( ip provided) using VS2008 windows form application.
i have wrote the below code which seems to be working fine only when i'm logged into any one of the remote servers, if i install the same application in my local machine and try to run it, i get below error :

'Query' is not recognized as internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
press any key to continue...

Note : if i just directly run 'system user /server:XXX' command via command prompt of my local machine, i will get the required details, without facing any error.

My doubt is, why am i facing error if i run the same command with my application?

PFB code which i have written :

```
static std::string toStandardString(System::String^ string)
         {
             using System::Runtime::InteropServices::Marshal;

             if (string->Length == 0 || string->Length < 0)
             {
                 MessageBox::Show("No field can be empty");

             }

             System::IntPtr pointer = Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi(string);
             char* charPointer = reinterpret_cast<char*>(pointer.ToPointer());
             std::string returnString(charPointer, string->Length);
             Marshal::FreeHGlobal(pointer);
             return returnString;
         }



#pragma endregion
private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {

             String^ com = "query user /server:";
             String^ texStr= textBox1->Text;
             String^ full = com + texStr + " & pause";
             std::string str1 = toStandardString(full);
             char str2[100];
             strcpy(str2,str1.c_str());
             system(str2);
             getch();

         }
```

TIA.

Comment: General: That's not C++ and C++/cli with Windows Forms is a bad idea. C++/cli was never meant for Application but as a glue between unmanaged and managed code. Try using `String^ com = "cmd /k query user /ser ...";` You shouldn't use `system()` though but the WinAPI or appropriate .NET-functions directly.

Comment: Hi Swordfish, i tried your suggestion, but still the error is same.

Comment: Can anybody reply over this? I've been stuck with this issue from past few days